# StandardScaler, fit() and transform()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I did this steps in a dataset that I'm working on:

```
StandardScaler
Boruta
Train and test model
```

Everything working! But now, I need to deploy this model and the problem is, I use the method .fit() in a dataset with 18 columns, but boruta selected just 8 columns, so the model was trained with 8 features. When I get new data, will be only 8 features and I need to transform before predict the answer.

So the question is, I fit the standardScaler with 18 features, and now I'm going to get just 8 features and I need to transform this 8 columns, but how?

I have this error:

```
ValueError: X has 8 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 18 features as input
```

I need to transform the 8 features before input on model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the same transformation that you used during the training phase to the new data that you want to make predictions on.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

# Load the StandardScaler object
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.mean_ = np.array([...])  # set the mean for each feature
scaler.var_ = np.array([...])   # set the variance for each feature

# Get new data with only 8 features
new_data = np.array([...])

# Reshape the new data to have 10 missing columns
new_data = np.concatenate((new_data, np.zeros((new_data.shape[0], 10))), axis=1)

# Fit the StandardScaler object to the new data
scaler.fit(new_data)

# Transform the new data
transformed_data = scaler.transform(new_data[:, :8])
```